# How to call a variable when its name is equal to a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, photoswipe

So we have some HTML here:

```
  <div class="button galleryButton" number="1">Gallery</div>
  <div class="button galleryButton" number="2">Gallery</div>
```

And two arrays:

```
      var room1 = [
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/tea.JPG',
          w: 700, // Those are just width and height 
          h: 300 //
        },
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/00039850.JPG',
          w: 600,
          h: 400
        }
      ];

      var room2 = [
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/somethingElse.JPG',
          w: 700,
          h: 300
        },
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/00039840.JPG',
          w: 600, 
          h: 400 
        }
      ];
```

We pick these buttons with

`var roomCounter = document.getElementsByClassName('galleryButton');`

And we loop through them so we can hold the selected room number in a variable

```
for (var i = 0; i < roomCounter.length; i++) {
  roomCounter[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var roomNumber = this.getAttribute("number");
      var thisRoom = 'room'+roomNumber;
```

So lets say we click on the first button:
 `thisRoom` now stores 'room1' string
(PhotoSwipe is a cool javascript gallery and 'thisRoom' should be an array of images in order to make it work.)
But here comes:

```
var newGallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, thisRoom, options);
```

It wont work, because it takes a simple string 'room1' instead of an array held in a variable.

**How can I make newGallery know that I want it to take an array equal to the value of thisRoom, not just a string?**

And also, if you see something that you find 'not very clear', 'just horribly bad' in my code or think there is a better approach, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store all your arrays in an object like this:

```
var myArrays = {
    "room1": [/*define array for "room1"*/],
    "room2": [/*define array for "room2"*/],
    //...
};
```

and then access the array you want using the key you generate like this:

```
var thisRoom = 'room'+roomNumber; // generate the key
myArrays[thisRoom]; // access the according array from myArrays.
```

And that how you would call `PhotoSwipe`:

```
var newGallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, myArrays[thisRoom], options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newGallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, eval(thisRoom), options);
```

```js
     var room1 = [
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/tea.JPG',
          w: 700, // Those are just width and height 
          h: 300 //
        },
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/00039850.JPG',
          w: 600,
          h: 400
        }
      ];

      var room2 = [
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/somethingElse.JPG',
          w: 700,
          h: 300
        },
        {
          src: './includes/imgs/Hotel/00039840.JPG',
          w: 600, 
          h: 400 
        }
      ];
      var roomCounter = document.getElementsByClassName('galleryButton');

for (var i = 0; i < roomCounter.length; i++) {
  roomCounter[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var roomNumber = this.getAttribute("number");
      var thisRoom = 'room'+roomNumber;
      var newGallery = alert(eval( thisRoom) );
      });
      }
```

```html
  <div class="button galleryButton" number="1">Gallery</div>
  <div class="button galleryButton" number="2">Gallery</div>
```

But remember that [eval is evil](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) so use it with care.

Answer (score 0):

`window` is an object that contains all variables declared in your document.

So if you declare a variable `var room1` there will be an attribute in `window` whith key being `room1` and its value being the value of the `room1` variable (i.e. `room1 values the same as window["room1"]`).

That is, you can access the content of the `room1` variable with `window[thisRoom]` like this:

```
var newGallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, window[thisRoom], options);
```

Comment: Only if they're declared in the global scope or declared without `var`.

Comment: I heard that declaring anything in the global scope is a no no. What do you think? It won't interfere much, since this is a really small project, but I believe it might become a real issue if it grew bigger

Comment: Well, if they are not directly in the global scope then they belong to an object in the global scope and you can retrieve it in the same way: `objectName[thisRoom]`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, just like your answer. It only works if `myArrays` is in the global scope. Change `myArrays` for `window` and it applies just the same way.

Comment: @MarcCompte but in my answer `myArrays` could be just in the same scope or in any higher scope (not necessarly the golbal one).